# Add/Edit Email field not shown when editing a contact

Tags: drupal, email

I have created a drupal civicrm site using version 4.7.14 and noticed for some reason when editing a contact I don't have the option to edit the contact's email address nor do I have the option to add an email. I can't even find the contact's email when viewing their contact info. Normally the email is found above "website" and below "source". I'm missing this necessary field. I have created multiple drupal civicrm sites before and I have never encountered this problem until now, is it possible that because I installed the latest Civicrm version this might be a bug? The other Civicrm sites I created are older than version 4.7.14. I hope someone can help me in figuring this out soon.

Here are a couple screenshots.

[image: No Email between source and website]
No Email between source and website

[image: No email found under contact details, also first and last name are missing under "individual name fields"]
No email found under contact details, also first and last name missing under "individual name fields"

-Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the code and can tell you what you're missing, but not why.

Run the following SQL statement on your CiviCRM database:

```
SELECT cov.* FROM civicrm_option_value cov JOIN civicrm_option_group cog ON cov.option_group_id = cog.id WHERE cog.name = "contact_edit_options";
```

You should get a result that looks like:

```
+-----+-----------------+---------------------------+-------+--------------------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+---------------+------+-------+
| id  | option_group_id | label                     | value | name                     | grouping | filter | is_default | weight | description | is_optgroup | is_reserved | is_active | component_id | domain_id | visibility_id | icon | color |
+-----+-----------------+---------------------------+-------+--------------------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+---------------+------+-------+
| 137 |              18 | Custom Data               | 1     | CustomData               | NULL     |      0 |       NULL |      1 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 138 |              18 | Address                   | 2     | Address                  | NULL     |      0 |       NULL |      2 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 139 |              18 | Communication Preferences | 3     | CommunicationPreferences | NULL     |      0 |       NULL |      3 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 140 |              18 | Notes                     | 4     | Notes                    | NULL     |      0 |       NULL |      4 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 141 |              18 | Demographics              | 5     | Demographics             | NULL     |      0 |       NULL |      5 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 142 |              18 | Tags and Groups           | 6     | TagsAndGroups            | NULL     |      0 |       NULL |      6 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 143 |              18 | Email                     | 7     | Email                    | NULL     |      1 |       NULL |      7 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 144 |              18 | Phone                     | 8     | Phone                    | NULL     |      1 |       NULL |      8 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 145 |              18 | Instant Messenger         | 9     | IM                       | NULL     |      1 |       NULL |      9 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 146 |              18 | Open ID                   | 10    | OpenID                   | NULL     |      1 |       NULL |     10 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 147 |              18 | Website                   | 11    | Website                  | NULL     |      1 |       NULL |     11 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 148 |              18 | Prefix                    | 12    | Prefix                   | NULL     |      2 |       NULL |     12 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 149 |              18 | Formal Title              | 13    | Formal Title             | NULL     |      2 |       NULL |     13 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 150 |              18 | First Name                | 14    | First Name               | NULL     |      2 |       NULL |     14 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 151 |              18 | Middle Name               | 15    | Middle Name              | NULL     |      2 |       NULL |     15 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 152 |              18 | Last Name                 | 16    | Last Name                | NULL     |      2 |       NULL |     16 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
| 153 |              18 | Suffix                    | 17    | Suffix                   | NULL     |      2 |       NULL |     17 | NULL        |           0 |           0 |         1 |         NULL |      NULL |          NULL | NULL | NULL  |
+-----+-----------------+---------------------------+-------+--------------------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+---------------+------+-------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note how all my options with a filter of "1" show are the items that appear in that list.  My guess is you're missing the "Email" record.

I don't know why - and that would concern me, because who knows what else is missing?  That said, you can fix this problem by inserting a row in the `civicrm_option_value` table for email.  The values may be slightly different for you than me (the `option_group_id` isn't always the same) but you should be able to figure out the values easily enough by looking at the values that are present in the database.

Comment: I got the same results with that following SQL statement, but still can't see the emails nor first and last name fields.

Comment: Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Option Groups**.  Select "Options" next to "contact_edit_options".  Do you see anything unusual?  Maybe those items aren't marked as "active"?

Comment: Wow thanks John, that did the trick!
The email, first and last name fields were disabled, but I re-enabled them. Then went to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences and checked Email, First and Last Name.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible that `email` field is disabled from your Display Preferences. You can find this on `Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences`.

Make sure `Email` field is checked `TRUE` on `Contact Details` Column of `Editing Contact` Section.

Demo Link - http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

Comment: I have tried that and I don't see the Email field at all. All I see under contact details is phone, instant messenger, open ID, and website.